# Lattice path from Project Euler with Python solution

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics

I was trying to solve this problem called lattice path from Project Euler:

> Count the number of unique paths to travel from the top left to the bottom right of a lattice of squares.

How many such routes are there through a 20×20 grid? It takes me forever to get an answer...

[image: https://projecteuler.net/project/images/p015.gif]
<sub>(source: [projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net/project/images/p015.gif))</sub>

> ```
>     #  Input:     An interger N (which is the size of the lattice)
>     #  Output:    An interger (which represents the number of unique paths)
>     #
>     #  Example:   input: 2
>     #
>     #             (2 x 2 lattice of squares)
>     #              __ __
>     #             |__|__|
>     #             |__|__|
>     #
> ```

When moving through the lattice, you can only move either down or to the right.

I currently have 1 solution, and I am not sure how much better if we memoize it. But I wanted to ask for code review for my solution below:

```
def lattice_paths(m, n):
    if m == 0 and n == 0:
        return 1
    if m < 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    return lattice_paths(m - 1, n) + lattice_paths(m, n - 1)

Here is the time complexity and space complexity of my first solution.
# Time Complexity: O(2^(M+N))
# Auxiliary Space Complexity: O(M+N)
```

Dynamic approach with the memorized solution:

```
def lattice_paths(m, n): # m rows and n columns


    def helper(x, y):

      if x > helper.m or y > helper.n:
        return 0
      if helper.cache.get((x, y)) is not None: 
        return helper.cache[(x, y)]

      helper.cache[(x, y)] = helper(x + 1, y) + helper(x, y + 1)
      return helper.cache[(x, y)]  
    helper.cache = {}

    helper.m = m
    helper.n = n
    helper(0,0)

    if m  ==  0 and n == 0:
      return 1
    elif m < 0 or n < 0:
      return 0
    else:
      return helper.cache[(0, 0)]
```

Comment: That's more of a mathematics and algorithm problem than a coding one. Check out this [excellent blog post](http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-15/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here's a solution that uses cache to memoize the solution

```
def lattice_paths(m, n):
    cache = [1]
    larger = max(m, n)
    smaller = min(m, n)
    while(len(cache) < larger + 1):
        for i in range(1, len(cache)):
            cache[i] += cache[i - 1]
        cache.append(2 * cache[len(cache) - 1])
    return cache[smaller]

# Time Complexity: O(N)
# Auxiliary Space Complexity: O(N)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of your approaches are very brute force.  The answer can be computed with a bit of mathematical reasoning.  For an *m* × *n* lattice, all paths will have *m* + *n* segments, of which *m* segments will go down and *n* segments will go right.  So, out of *m* + *n* slots, count the ways to pick *m* downward moves; the rest of them will be rightward moves.  The number of paths is:

$${m + n \choose m} = {m + n \choose n} = \frac{(m+n)!}{m! \, n!}$$

So, the Python solution is simply:

```
from math import factorial

def lattice_paths(m, n):
    return factorial(m + n) // factorial(m) // factorial(n)
```

Even though the calculation involves large factorials, Python supports big integers seamlessly, and arrives at the answer nearly instantaneously.